# .Net Core 3.1 WPF using System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

I am have a .Net Core 3.1 WPF application and trying to incorporate charts. I have added the NuGet package
System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit" Version="4.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

While I find that works and I am able to create charts, I get an warning in the dependencies/Packages:
`Package 'System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit 4.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.`

Any suggestions on how to get rid of the warning?

Answer (score 0):

The package [*System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit*](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit/) only contains assemblies for the .NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile. Consequently it is **not compatible** with .NET Core in any version.

Since this package is not an official package by Microsoft and there are no updates for .NET Core, I guess there is nothing you can do about it, except for searching an alternative or going back to .NET Framework.

Comment: Since the path way is away from .Net Framework and towards .Net 5 that would seem to be a step backwards. WPF is supported in .Net Core so there should be a charting package as well.

Comment: @Jeff This package was last updated in 2014 and is not official. However, since there is a [similar official package for WinForms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization/1.0.0-prerelease.20110.1), there might be a chance that the WPF counterpart may get a .NET Core compatible successor, too, but for now there isn't one.